# Markdown: Link to an inter-doc section where the title contains a '-' character

Tags: markdown

I have a link to a section, in Markdown, like this:

```
[Creating GPU enabled on premises configurations](#install-gpu-support-in-an-on-premises-environment)
```

The section is title like this:

```
## Install GPU support in an on-premises environment
```

This is flagged by my link checker as broken, because, I believe it is looking for a section titled:

```
## Install GPU support in an on premises environment
```

A section title with out the `-`. I've looked and not been able to find how to escape the `-` in Markdown. (I know there is a way in Asciidoc.)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

[Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) doesn't generate header anchors (or tables of contents), but many implementations do. We can't answer this without knowing the specific implementation.

I believe GitHub, for example, will work just fine with the link you show in your question.

Open the rendered Markdown in a browser and mouse over the generated link to see what you should link to, then update your link accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-breaking hyphen (`‑`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

Turns out if i do something like this

```
[Creating GPU enabled on premises configurations](#install-gpu-support-in-an-on\-premises-environment)
```

This worked fine!

Thanks for the help!